# White text in menu

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this css. I would like when I hover the mouse over an item the text color turns blue and the background stays white. I would also like the menu text to be white. What happens is that when I hover with the mouse, since the `.menu li:hover` item must have a white background, even the text, if I put

```
a {
    color: white;
}
```

it stays white. How can I solve this?

```css
.menu{
  list-style-type: none;

  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1D72B9, #35A8E0);
  padding: 30px 0 30px 30px;
}

.menu li{
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}



.menu li:hover{
  background: white;
}


a:focus,a:hover{
    outline:0;
    color: #1D72B9;
    text-decoration:none
}

.menu li:hover:after,
.menu li:hover:before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  color:white;
}

.menu li:hover:after{
  top: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top left,  10px, white 11px);
}

.menu li:hover:before{
  bottom: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, 10px, white 11px);
}


a {

    color: white;

}



li,ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="<%= restaurants_restaurant_profile_path %>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Profile</span></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<%= restaurants_reservation_book_path %>"><i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Reservation Book</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Statistics</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> CRM</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Settings</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Support</span></a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only changing the link colour when you hover over the link itself, but you're changing the background colour when you hover over the `<li>`.

Since the link is not a block element, it doesn't expand to fill the available space, so if you hover over the `<li>` to the right of the link, you're *not* hovering over the link.

Change the `<a>` to `display:block;` and `color:inherit;`. Move the padding from the `<li>` to the `<a>`. And set the colour on the `li:hover` instead of `a:hover`.

```css
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1D72B9, #35A8E0);
  color: white;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 30px;
}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background: white;
  color: #1D72B9;
}
.menu a {
  display: block;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 5px;
}

.menu a:focus {
  outline: 0;
  text-decoration: none
}

.menu li:hover:after,
.menu li:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.menu li:hover:after {
  top: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top left, 10px, white 11px);
}

.menu li:hover:before {
  bottom: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, 10px, white 11px);
}

a {
  color: white;
}

li,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="<%= restaurants_restaurant_profile_path %>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Profile</span></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<%= restaurants_reservation_book_path %>"><i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Reservation Book</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Statistics</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> CRM</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Settings</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Support</span></a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want.

```css
li:hover a{
color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make your `<a>` full width and height of the li.

If you give the `<a>` an display block it will work. also add the padding in the `<a>`then instead of the `<li>`.

OR

Make the hover on the li instead the a

```css
.menu li:hover a { 
   color: yourColor;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to declare style for hovered links separetely (`a:hover`), you can just add css for links, which inside of hovered parent element like this:

```css
.menu li:hover a {
    outline:0;
    color: #1D72B9;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

It means style will be applies to *links wrapped into "li" wrapper into element with "menu" class when "li" is hovered*.

Your solution:

```css
.menu{
  list-style-type: none;

  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #1D72B9, #35A8E0);
  padding: 30px 0 30px 30px;
}

.menu li{
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}



.menu li:hover{
  background: white;
}

.menu li:hover a {
  outline:0;
  color: #1D72B9;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.menu li:hover:after,
.menu li:hover:before{
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  color:white;
}

.menu li:hover:after{
  top: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top left,  10px, white 11px);
}

.menu li:hover:before{
  bottom: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, 10px, white 11px);
}


a {

    color: white;

}



li,ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="<%= restaurants_restaurant_profile_path %>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Profile</span></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<%= restaurants_reservation_book_path %>"><i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Reservation Book</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Statistics</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> CRM</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Settings</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Support</span></a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1D72B9, #35A8E0);
  padding: 30px 0 30px 30px;
}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background: white;
}

.menu li:hover > a {/*use of child operator*/
  outline: 0;
  color: #1D72B9;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:focus,
a:hover {
  outline: 0;
  color: #1D72B9;
  text-decoration: none
}

.menu li:hover:after,
.menu li:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.menu li:hover:after {
  top: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top left, 10px, white 11px);
}

.menu li:hover:before {
  bottom: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, 10px, white 11px);
}

a {
  color: white;
}

li,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="<%= restaurants_restaurant_profile_path %>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Profile</span></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<%= restaurants_reservation_book_path %>"><i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Reservation Book</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Statistics</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> CRM</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Settings</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Support</span></a></li>

</ul>
```

## simply use > operator

> [get reference here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

- this answer maintains your style including `display:none` and no additional steps required

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you the result wanted?

```css
.menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1D72B9, #35A8E0);
  padding: 30px 0 30px 30px;
}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
}

.menu li:hover {
  background: white;
}

.menu li:focus a,
.menu li:hover a {
  outline: 0;
  color: #1D72B9;
  text-decoration: none
}

.menu li:hover:after,
.menu li:hover:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  color: white;
}

.menu li:hover:after {
  top: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top left, 10px, white 11px);
}

.menu li:hover:before {
  bottom: -10px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom left, 10px, white 11px);
}

a {
  color: white;
}

li,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="<%= restaurants_restaurant_profile_path %>"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Profile</span></a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="<%= restaurants_reservation_book_path %>"><i class="fa fa-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Reservation Book</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chart-bar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Statistics</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> CRM</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Settings</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm"> Support</span></a></li>

</ul>
```